# How To get variable stat

Tags: javascript

I will take the stat variable, but when in the console log the variable does not appear

```js
var stat;

document.getElementById("dataid1").addEventListener("change", function(){
  if (document.getElementById("dataid1").checked == true){
  stat = true;
 } else {
  stat = false;
 }
});

console.log(stat);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="dataid1" checked>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `console.log` needs to be inside the event listener callback. With the `console.log` outside, it runs once immediately. The event listener callback is invoked whenever the input changes. With the `console.log` inside, it will log the value every time it changes.

If you need to do something specific with the `stat` value when it changes, that logic should live in the event callback function.

```js
var stat;

document.getElementById("dataid1").addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (document.getElementById("dataid1").checked == true) {
    stat = true;
  } else {
    stat = false;
  }

  console.log(stat);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="dataid1" checked>
```